# Usage of strings for calling function

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

I have one really big question. For example:
I need to import one module according to given string and i use something like

```
string = 'testmodule'
module = __import__(string)
```

And it works. Now I need to call a function from that module also from a given string

```
return module.function()
```

needs to work on like:

```
string = 'function'
module = 'testmodule'
return module.string()
```

I know I can use ***exec*** and I am using currently it like

```
string = 'function'
module = 'testmodule'
exec('ret = ' + module + '.' + string + '()')
```

But how to do it without using that exec method because it is too slow?

Comment: Prefer [`importlib.import_module`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/importlib.html) to [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__). It works better with modules in packages. `__import__` is an old way of customizing the behavior of the `import` statement.

Comment: I always avoid `__doubleunderscore__` stuff when an alternative to it exists. It's basically  a signal that you're messing with stuff under the hood that elegant code seldom should touch. Unless I'm explicitly writing MetaClass code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
module = __import__('module')
func = getattr(module, 'func')
func()
```

If you wan't a more general solution, take a look at the [get_object](https://github.com/alefnula/tea/blob/master/src/tea/utils/__init__.py#L11) function from this file. You can provide a full path: `get_object('module.submodule.function')` or a relative path and an object: `get_object('submodule.function', module)` and it will return you the desired object.